# Flutter align button to bottom of Drawer

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to have a Widget align to the bottom of my NavDrawer while still keeping a DrawerHeader and a list at the top of the Drawer. Here's what I'm trying:

```
drawer: Drawer(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Top'),
        Align(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
          child: Text('Bottom'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

The bottom text should be aligned to the bottom of the drawer, but It isn't!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to wrap your `Align` widget in `Expanded`.

```
drawer: Drawer(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Top'),
      Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Text('Bottom'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: how to align button to bottom, but align other children to center (not top)? Mb better to use stack?

Comment: Can you explain how "Expanded" works? Every time I use it I run into either overflow errors or something about ```Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.```

Comment: This answer should be reviewed. I got "hasSize()" asserts when putting a ListView() where Text("Top") is. You have todo it the other way around. Expand the ListView then bottom text. Like the answer from Samuel Huff https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193080/8666381

Answer (score 49):

Edit:

Years on and there's a much easier solution:

```dart
return Drawer(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      ListView(), // <-- Whatever actual content you want goes here
      Spacer(), // <-- This will fill up any free-space
      // Everything from here down is bottom aligned in the drawer
      Divider(),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Settings'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Help and Feedback'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.help),
      ),
    ]
);
```

A little late to the party, but here's my solution to this problem:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      // column holds all the widgets in the drawer
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            // ListView contains a group of widgets that scroll inside the drawer
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                UserAccountsDrawerHeader(),
                Text('In list view'),
                Text('In list view too'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // This container holds the align
          Container(
              // This align moves the children to the bottom
              child: Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                  // This container holds all the children that will be aligned
                  // on the bottom and should not scroll with the above ListView
                  child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Divider(),
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                          title: Text('Settings')),
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                          title: Text('Help and Feedback'))
                    ],
                  )
                )
              )
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This produces the below output where the UserAccountDrawerHeader and the text items can be scrolled around inside the drawer but the Divider and the two ListTiles stay static on the bottom of the drawer.

[image: Output]

Comment: Parabéns obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 13):

If you take a look at your code, you have added a Column as a Child to the Drawer. So whatever you add in the column is vertically placed and The height of the Column is by default shrunk to its children's height and it gets larger as the child gets, so there's no point in adding an Align inside a Column.

The Simpler Solution would be to use an Expanded Widget that takes the remaining Space, In the below code I have used a Column and added A widget above and below the Expanded Widget.

```
  Drawer(
        elevation: 1.5,
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          )),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text('My Cart'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('My Orders'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                  title: Text('Logout'),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                  onTap: () {})
            ],
          )),
          Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 0.1,
          ),
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 100,
              child: Text("V1.0.0",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
        ])),
```

[image: Heres The Ouptut]

Answer (score 6):

A simple approach would be to use `Spacer()` like:

```
Scaffold(
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Top'),
        Spacer(), // use this
        Text('Bottom'),
      ],
    ),
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution of a vertical `Row` with icons in the end of the drawer.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppColors.menuHeaderColor,
                  ),
                  child: buildHeader(),
                ),
                AccountDrawerRow(),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                  title: Text(translations.button.vehicles),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  title: Text(translations.button.appointments,),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SettingsPage())),
                        child: Icon(Icons.settings)),
                    Icon(Icons.help),
                    Icon(Icons.info),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer based on Flutter 3.13.4 (September 2023)

```
drawer: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext _, BoxConstraints constraints) => Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth * 0.75,
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: DrawerHeader(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 15,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade600,
                        child: const Text('AH'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverList.list(
                    children: const <ListTile>[
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Profile'),
                        leading: Icon(Icons.people),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Calendar'),
                        leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Cart'),
                        leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Location'),
                        leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Settings'),
                        leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Help and Feedback'),
                        leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SliverFillRemaining(
                    hasScrollBody: false,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(),
                        ),
                        const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Logout'),
                            leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put it in a row and align all the stuff to bottom using `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline`

```
Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  '12.00',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                ),
                Text(
                  'USD',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                ),
              ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Expanded widget to align widget to bottom of column parent widget

```
Column(
            children: [
              ..other children
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Text(
                    'Button',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```